# GoogleAPIClient not connecting properly?

Tags: java, android, google-api, connection, google-api-client

I'm trying to connect mGoogleAPIClient, following [this Guide](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/api-client).
When i debug, a little window popsup asking me what googleplus account i would like to sign in as. As soon as I select my main account and click OK, it stops from there and does absolutely nothing. No error Messages, Warnings, Infos, no nothing.

My Source:
    public class MainMenu_Activity extends Activity implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {

```
    private Button btnStart;
    private Button btnSubmit;
    private Button btnHOF;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    public static int REQUEST_LEADERBOARD = 100;
    // Request code to use when launching the resolution activity
    private static final int REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR = 1001;
    // Bool to track whether the app is already resolving an error
    private boolean mResolvingError = false;
    private static final String STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR = "resolving_error";

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_mainmenu);

        mResolvingError = savedInstanceState != null
                && savedInstanceState.getBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, false);

        this.mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addApi(Drive.API)
                .addScope(Drive.SCOPE_FILE)
                .addApi(Plus.API)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_LOGIN)
                .addScope(Plus.SCOPE_PLUS_PROFILE)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .build();

    }

    @Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (!mResolvingError) {  // more about this later
            mGoogleApiClient.connect();
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        mGoogleApiClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(Bundle connectionHint) {
        // Connected to Google Play services!
        // The good stuff goes here.
        System.out.println("CONNECTED!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int cause) {
        // The connection has been interrupted.
        // Disable any UI components that depend on Google APIs
        // until onConnected() is called.
        System.out.println("SUSPENDED!");
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(ConnectionResult result) {
        System.out.println("Connection Failed - mResolvingError=" + mResolvingError);
        if (mResolvingError) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed - Already attempting to resolve...");
            // Already attempting to resolve an error.
            return;
        } else if (result.hasResolution()) {
            System.out.println("Connection Failed - resolving now...");
            try {
                mResolvingError = true;
                result.startResolutionForResult(this, REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR);
            } catch (IntentSender.SendIntentException e) {
                System.out.println("Connection Failed - Exception...");
                // There was an error with the resolution intent. Try again.
                mGoogleApiClient.connect();
            }
        } else {
            // Show dialog using GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog()
            Dialog errDia = GooglePlayServicesUtil.getErrorDialog(result.getErrorCode(), this, 1);
            errDia.show();
            mResolvingError = true;
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == REQUEST_RESOLVE_ERROR) {
            mResolvingError = false;
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
                // Make sure the app is not already connected or attempting to connect
                if (!mGoogleApiClient.isConnecting() &&
                        !mGoogleApiClient.isConnected()) {
                    mGoogleApiClient.connect();
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putBoolean(STATE_RESOLVING_ERROR, mResolvingError);
    }
  }
```

As you can see, i tagged certain places to follow the procedure.
Well this is what the logcat logs:

> 06-02 17:52:48.175    2302-2302/com.dudewithfacial.game.gamebase I/System.out﹕
>   Connection Failed - mResolvingError=false 06-02 17:52:48.175
>   2302-2302/com.dudewithfacial.game.gamebase I/System.out﹕ Connection Failed -
>   resolving now...

I follow the guide step by step :(
Well appaently not really, what am i doing wrong Stackoverflow-Gurus?
Thx boys, really appreciated!

Comment: Update: Getting this Error: 
06-02 18:42:20.656    2391-7463/? W/ActivityManager﹕ mDVFSHelper.acquire()
06-02 18:42:20.656    2391-7463/? W/ActivityManager﹕ Activity is launching as a new task, so cancelling activity result.

Answer (score 0):

NVM, figured out i can't use Launchmode, SingleUser, SingleInstance.
Also haven't configred some of the requested APIs such as ".addApi(Plus.API)"

Problem fixed.